# `eth_getBlockTransactionCountByHash` returns null even when `--txlookuplimit=0` is set

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, full-node

As the title says the following RPC method `eth_getBlockTransactionCountByHash` only returns `null`. Geth node is running on `Goerli` & am using a valid testnet block to fetch the following info. What could be the possible problem?

Command used:

```sh
curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBlockTransactionCountByHash","params":["0x78723a14676c6c59491c43b7c316cd4c5b31c6b789a8bbb21116a94caa7dbf60"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem come from the fact that Geth node not having complete historical transaction data, by default `Geth` is in `fast` syncro mod, so your node only retains the last 1024 blocks' state trie data and it does not know transaction data for older blocks.

The easiest solution is to run your node in `full` mod `geth --goerli --syncmode full`
notice that it will require more disk space and time to synchronize, as it downloads and processes all historical transaction data.

Comment: You are definitely right, I don't see that `--syncmode full` flag in my config file meaning I'm running on 'snap'. Can I just turn the node off & add that flag & start downloading that extra data?

Comment: yes that would work, geth will start downloading the extra data required for a full node